# Is there a GUI type "choice" app for OS X? (similar to choice.com for PC)

Tags: macos

I'm running a terminal script and I would really like to send option choices to the OS X GUI, similar to how `choice.com` works for Windows / DOS, but a GUI version.

I know I can use applescript's `choose from list` command, but I would prefer a more native app because I think it would run quicker, as well as being more stable and more straight forward to interface with.

I have installed Platypus, and I like how it has the option to output data to a GUI window - but I would like the functionality of passing data back to the script from such a window.

One example scenario might be an easy way to select from a list of folders. This is what it looks like when I do it with Applescript:

[image]

```
set listOfNames to {}
tell application "Finder"
    set filelist to every window
    repeat with currentFile in filelist
        set currentFileName to (POSIX path of (target of currentFile as alias)) as string
        copy currentFileName to the end of listOfNames
    end repeat
end tell
set mySelection to choose from list listOfNames
```

However, I would really prefer not to use Applescript.

#### Resources

Until I can find (or build) the perfect app to do this, I might have to use Applescript. I'm going to list a few resources I've found:

A clever way to do multi-line applescript from the terminal:

Code [from here](http://forums.macnn.com/90/mac-os-x/160622/how-pass-parameter-terminal-applescript-osascript/):

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename: find_me 
# usage from Terminal prompt: find_me "Last First"

osascript -e "set the_name to \"$1\"" -e 'on find_me (the_name)
   tell application "Address Book"
     set the_people to every person
     repeat with this_name in the_people
          if name of this_name contains the_name then 
             set result to name of this_name & "\n" 
             repeat with e_info in emails of this_name
               set result to result & value of e_info & " "
             end repeat
               set result to result & "\n"
             repeat with p_info in phones of this_name
               set result to result & value of p_info & " "
             end repeat 
             return result
         end if
     end repeat
   end tell
end find_me' -e 'find_me(the_name)'
```

Also noteworthy from that page: "osascript does not yet provide any way to pass arguments to the script"

"But there is a workaround:"

```
call osascript -e 'set thename to '$1 -e 'load script "/path/to/script"' -e 'look_up_name(thename)'
```

And my contribution, a way to force the dialog to be in focus:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e "set front_app_name to short name of (info for (path to frontmost application))
    set listOfNames to {"a", "b", "c"}
    tell application front_app_name to choose from list listOfNames"
```

It is also good to note that you can use multiple -e commands to pass multiple strings to be run.

Comment: Using AppleScript is probably your best option.

Comment: Also, `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to choose from list { "a", "b" }'` is instantaneous on my machine.

Comment: I haven't learned much about ApplesScipt, but indeed, what I've seen, makes it seem like a great solution. With my skill set, I'd try to use a Python driven GUI, probably through tcl/tk. But that's probably not what you mean by native app.

If you were to write a Native App for this, you can call it from the terminal using the "open" command. I can imagine horrifying ways of interfacing that gui to a backend, but I will not share those as they're pretty horrid.

Comment: I'm trying to call the script with Quicksilver, so I'm not sure Daniel's oascript, `tell application "Terminal"` is the best solution because it launches Terminal if it is not running. If I try and use `tell application "Quicksilver"` the dialog is not focused when it appears (keyboard nav not possible without a click). Seems like these problems would go away if there was a native app that could accept a list of choices and a callback - or even better if there was a Quciksilver plugin that allowed the results to be returned and displayed as a menu instead of just a block of text.

Comment: If this is the only issue you face, just use `Finder` and `activate` it. I used Terminal as example, as it's the front application when using `osascript` from within it. I didn't expect you to actually have all the other code in AppleScript, since you don't want to actually use it.

Comment: You still haven't actually explained what's wrong with AppleScript and how it doesn't fit what you want to do. You can write AppleScript in Xcode. Developing Cocoa applications in AppleScript is supported in Xcode 4. It sounds like you want to write something largely in AppleScript (such as your example), or one of the other scripting languages (ruby, perl, bash, …) so there shouldn't be anything wrong with invoking another, more integrated scripting language for the user interaction. If you want to create an actual *application* using e.g. C, use Cocoa instead.

Comment: I dislike the applescript approach to this because it is hacky and unstable. Applescript is powerful, but I think in many cases it is pushed beyond its intended use. I updated the question to show some "workarounds" to fix the issues, but if Applescript was *meant* to be integrated this way the issues would not exist in the first place. I may work on writing a non Applescript solution if I have time, and share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CocoaDialog](http://cocoadialog.sourceforge.net/)

`/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog dropdown --title "Titlebar" --text "Prompt" --items A B --button1 OK --button2 Cancel`

Comment: yes, yes yes! Thanks! Exactly what I was asking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Like Daniel Beck says in the comments: AppleScript is your best option. It's just as "native" as anything else (Cocoa, Carbon), if not more so (Python, Perl, tcl/tk, etc.).

Comment: I think of "Native" as meaning software that was compiled for a particular OS (http://www.unfocus.com/2011/03/25/what-is-a-native-app/). Since AppleScript is not compiled, but rather requires the AppleScript engine to load in order to parse it, I would say that it is less native than Cocoa and Carbon apps. I don't think you're going to visit the App Store and buy anything written in AppleScript.

Comment: @cwd You can, in fact, get AppleScript apps on the App Store. While Cocoa apps are most often written in Objective-C, they can be written in AppleScript, too. Here is AppleScript app on the App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-analyzer/id422302958?mt=12

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you know that one was written in Applescript?

Comment: @cwd The author has ranted about things related to AppleScript and the App Store (separately) in relation to the app, both on Twitter and his blog.

Comment: I would like to mention that application is actually written in AppleScriptObjC and not just Applescript.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "not AppleScript" answer, but there is a better way to get arguments into an AppleScript:

```
osascript -e '
  on run(args)
    ... choose from list args ...
  end
' 1 2 3
```

This avoids quoting issues, so you can pass arbitrary strings (don't forget to `"$quote"` your shell variables!)